# How to pass markdown text to markdown blade in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-mail

I need to send markdown e-mail in Laravel but, text of this email must be editable. When I pass `$body` to a related view, it displays this way:

```php
$body = '''
# Introduction
hi {{ $username }} 
The body of your {{ $family }}.

@component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
Button Text
@endcomponent
'''
```

In the related view in blade:

```php
@component('mail::message')

    {{ $body }}

Thanks,<br>
{{ config('app.name') }}
@endcomponent
```

and this is output:[image: laravel-output]

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: Your `$body` variable is a string literal, I don't see how do you think this could work?

Comment: so ... how can i to  convert this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just change it to view blade:

```
{!! $body !!}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of passing it as a string, you put the whole body in the view blade you already have, with all the above variables, like this:

```
  @component('mail::message')
    
       hi {{ $username }} 
       The body of your {{ $family }}.

       @component('mail::button', ['url' => ''])
          Button Text
       @endcomponent
    
       Thanks,<br>
       {{ config('app.name') }}
    @endcomponent
```

And then, when sending a mail, just pass all the variables you need to that view. Since I'm not sure how are you sending your emails, here's the example using Mailable class:

```
Mail::to('email_address')->send(new MailableClass($username, $family));
```

Then, your Mailable class would look like this:

```
public function __construct($username, $family)
    {
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->family = $family;
    }

    
    public function build()
    {
        $data['username'] = $this->username;
        $data['family'] = $this->family;

        return $this
            ->view('your_blade', $data)
            ->subject('Subject');
    }
```

And then, your variables will be displayed in the given view.

Answer (score 0):

I tried passing my markdown content as a variable, to an empty Blade file, as suggested by @Noorbala but it didn't work.

The blade directives were not processed by my Mailable class (e.g. `@component`).

**Why?**

It looks like the `render` method in `Illuminate\Mail\Markdown.php` will replace mail components from the Blade view file (as it is), before the variables are replaced.

**Workaround**

Not ideal, but for now I ended up modifying an actual file (used only as a placeholder).

Note: You may want to git ignore this file, or update back to be empty.

```
class CampaignFormat extends Mailable
{
    protected $markdownContent;

    public function __construct($markdownContent)
    {
        $this->markdownContent = $markdownContent;
    }

    /**
     * Required, since it won't let me pass the content to the file as a string variable.
     * It expects to have the component directives directly on the actual blade file.
     */
    const DYNAMIC_MARKDOWN_TEMPLATE_PATH = 'views/emails/dynamic_markdown_template.blade.php';

    /**
     * The render method invokes this one internally.
     */
    public function build()
    {        
        $this->markdown('emails.dynamic_markdown_template')
            ->with('markdownContent', $this->markdownContent);
    }
    
    private function updateTemplateFileTemporarily()
    {
        // Update the file with the desired content
        File::put(resource_path(self::DYNAMIC_MARKDOWN_TEMPLATE_PATH), $this->markdownContent);   
    }
    
    private function clearTemplateFile()
    {
        // Clear the file so it doesn't keep changes
        File::put(resource_path(self::DYNAMIC_MARKDOWN_TEMPLATE_PATH), '');
    }

    /**
     * It does the magic.
     */
    public function dynamicRender(): string
    {
        $this->updateTemplateFileTemporarily();
        $html = $this->render();
        $this->clearTemplateFile();
        return $html;
    }

}
```

In my case I use it just to get the rendered HTML, and store it into my database.

The email service I use will take care of sending the HTML, in batches to my users.